# Design help: threading within a struct

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm new to Rust. As a learning exercise I'm trying to write a simple timer struct that I once wrote in C++. The interface and implementation looks something like this:

```
pub struct Timer {
    handle: Option<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    alive: bool,
}

impl Timer {
    pub fn new() {
        Timer {
            handle: None,
            alive: false,
        }
    }

    pub fn start(&'static mut self) {
        // Oops! How do I do this?
        self.handle = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
            self.alive = true;
            self.loop()
        }));
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.alive = false;
        self.handle.unwrap().join()
    }

    pub fn loop(&self) {
        // while alive
    }
}
```

I understand why this is an error because of `use of moved value: self` within the `start` function, but I'm wondering how I'm supposed to *design* my struct so that something like this would work. In every scenario I can think of, I'll always have a double borrow situation.

I have a hunch that I need to learn more about interior mutability, but figured I would ask for design guidance before going down any more rabbit holes.

Comment: Your `struct` definition and `impl` do not line up. In the definition it has one member (`handle`) and in the implementation of `new` it has two members (`thread` and `alive`). I kinda guess what it should be, but it'd be better if they matched what you have in your code.

Comment: I'll work on cleaning it up more, I simplified a lot of the code in order to keep the example concise.

Comment: Yes, I can see it's been distilled down to its essentials and I appreciate the effort you put in :) Just trying to dot the is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are pretty close to getting it to work.

There are only two hurdles:

- `thread::spawn` will not allow sharing references
- `alive` and `loop` for you to share in this design

The solution is two-fold:

- split up things between the controller (`Timer`) and the worker (the closure)
- share state between the two using `Arc` since references are forbidden

Here is a minimal example for you to toy with:

```
use std::{sync, thread, time};
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};

pub struct Timer {
    handle: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    alive: sync::Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl Timer {
    pub fn new() -> Timer {
        Timer {
            handle: None,
            alive: sync::Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false)),
        }
    }

    pub fn start<F>(&mut self, fun: F)
        where F: 'static + Send + FnMut() -> ()
    {
        self.alive.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);

        let alive = self.alive.clone();

        self.handle = Some(thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut fun = fun;
            while alive.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
                fun();
                thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
            }
        }));
    }

    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.alive.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);
        self.handle
            .take().expect("Called stop on non-running thread")
            .join().expect("Could not join spawned thread");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut timer = Timer::new();
    timer.start(|| println!("Hello, World!") );

    println!("Feeling sleepy...");
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));

    println!("Time for dinner!");
    timer.stop();
}
```

I invite you to poke holes at it one at a time (ie, change one thing that is different from your example, check the error message, and try to understand how the difference solved it).

On the playground, it printed for me:

```
Feeling sleepy...
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Time for dinner!
```

Though I would not rely on (1) the number of times `"Hello, World!"` appears and (2) `"Feeling sleepy..."` appearing first.

*And damned, is `Atomic` verbose... I kinda wish there was a `get`/`set` with `SeqCst` (the stronger ordering) available.*

Comment: Thanks. My example didn't clearly emphasize that I would like the thread closure to be able to operate over additional state in the `Timer`. E.g., the loop function would like to signal a condition variable that users can wait for. Your approach (which passes in an external callable) still doesn't let me do this. Any additional thoughts on that? I'm going to keep playing with this example now, thanks again.

Comment: For full transparency, I'm fiddling around by reimplementing this class: https://github.com/sholsapp/gallocy/blob/master/gallocy/include/gallocy/consensus/timer.h

Comment: @sholsapp: The key is to deal with that like I dealt with `alive`. You don't need a reference-counted self, just reference-counted *members* of self. You can either have a single `data` member which is `Arc<(Mutex<YourData>, CondVar)>` or you can have multiple members each reference-counted independently.

Comment: Ah... this makes sense... and while I've been playing around that's starting to become clear. Based on my full C++ example I linked to, really the only reference counted members I need to pass to the closure are `alive` and `timed_out`, relinquishing all other state directly to the closure. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, I'm confused why the compiler won't let me use `self.loop()` in the closure. If I inline this directly in the closure, things work. Is there a way to "cast" the mutable reference to a immutable one to satisfy the borrow checker?

Comment: @sholsapp: mutability is not the issue, lifetime is. The signature of `spawn` requires that the closure be `'static`, because the thread spawned could outlive... well anything really. Since the lifetime of `Timer` is not static, you cannot pass `&self` or `&mut self` to `spawn`, and therefore you cannot call any method of `self` inside the closure passed to `spawn`. In your code, you attempted to work around that by using `'static` as the lifetime of `self`, but that's not how lifetimes work. Lifetime are like Oxygen, they exist whether we name them or not, naming is documenting not directing.

Comment: Thank you again, this was a big help, and I understand the problem with my former approach. Thanks for the example that used the `Atomic` type, too, I knew nothing about these before.